# Download Attachment using php is not working for xlsm files

Tags: rest-api, api, attachment, php, curl

I'm using the below `php code` to save the Attachment to my server.

```
 public function getAttachmentFileFromSalesForce($fileName, $fileBodyUrl)
    {
        try {
            $authCode='';
            $instanceUrl = '';
            $filePath = storage_path('sf_files') . '/' . $fileName;
            $headers= array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $authCode);
            $ch = curl_init($instanceUrl . $fileBodyUrl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
            $tempFP = fopen($filePath, 'w+');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $tempFP);
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            fclose($tempFP);
            return true;

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //silence
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This is working fine for **pdf** files. But in the case of **xlsm**, the file shows some junk data like below.

> 戮J9�ε�����o��/��N�o���L�Z�:%m���S�/k
>   ����)�3iG�E$v��Ď7��q�o#��4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got worked by **removing** the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option.

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //remove
```